# Deriving the equation for variance

Tags: self-study, variance

I am trying to understand variance, and when I look at the fully derived equation on wikipedia, I do not understand how we are able to make the jump from B to C.

[image: screenshot of wikipedia]

When simplifying, `2(XE[X])` where does the `2X` go? I understand how we get `2E[X]`, but I'm not sure why or how the 2X is able to be removed.

Comment: This is not a stupid question. It's not just simplifying... notice that B has an expectation of the entire expression, while C does not. (And welcome to CV, snarkshark!)

Comment: Hi, @Alexis :) I noticed that, but I'm still confused. Does E[-2XE[X]] somehow become 1? I dont understand how its eliminated from the equation still :'(

Comment: As an aside, you might read about the [tag:self-study] tag, and edit your question (the "edit" link at lower left) to inlcude it.

Comment: Well simplifying *does* enter thereafter. What is $E[(-2)]$? What is $E[(X)]$? What is $E[(E[X])]$? And so, what is $E[(-2XE[X])]$?

Comment: E[(-2)] = -2 (averaging itself is just itself);
E[X] = X; and
E[(E[X])] = E[X] = X; 
so... 
 [(−2[])] just ends up being -2X and its removed from the equation because its a constant?
Thanks for your patience with my dumb questions ^^;;

Comment: $E[(X)] = E[X]$, not $X$. And $E[E[X]] = E[X]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You distribute $E[.]$ operator into each summand, since it is a linear operator by definition. So, the middle term is $E[2XE[X]]=2E[XE[X]]$. When calculated $E[X]$ is constant, and therefore removed from the expectation (let $E[X]=\mu$):

$$2E[X\mu]=2\mu E[X]=2E[X]E[X]=2E[X]^2$$

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for taking the time to answer. A few questions:
1) Why do you put a dot in E[.] operator? Is this some kind of common notation?
2) To clarify, since E[] is essentially just an averaging equation, is that why you can move the 2 outside of the inner E[]?
I don't really have the intuition for it being linear and such yet ^^;;

Comment: @snarkshark, 1. it doesn't have a special meaning. Notationally, dot generally refers to *some expression*. 2. Intuitionally yes. If average of $X$ is $E[X]$, then average of $aX$ is $aE[X]$. Mathematically, Think about $E[f(X)]=\sum f(x)p_X(x)$ for discrete RVs. If $f(X)=aX$, where $a$ is a constant, then $E[aX]=\sum axp_X(x)=a\sum x p_X(x)$. Situation is similar if $\sum$ is replaced by $\int$ when the variable is continuous.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that summation symbols always implied discrete :) Thanks! That makes a lot more sense now. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The `2X` doesn't disappear. When you distribute the E[] operator, it turns into `2E[X]`. Thus `E[... -2XE[X] + ...]` becomes `... - 2E[X]E[X] + ...` (because `E[E[X]]=E[X]`) and then the term simplifies with the other `E[X]²` term.